# How to add a new lines of text to an existing "textarea" using protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I would need to add new lines of text at specific position of "textarea" using protractor, there is no element to identify, it is just a textarea.

Help would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about simple textarea element (like this http://www.protractortest.org/testapp/ng1/#/form ) then you should be fine with default `.sendKeys()` , just call it without `.clear()` , here is example:

```
describe('test1', function () {
    it('1', function () {
         browser.get('http://www.protractortest.org/testapp/ng1/#/form');
        var textarea = element(By.model('aboutbox'));
        textarea.getAttribute('value').then(console.log);
        textarea.sendKeys(' MORE KEYS!')
        textarea.getAttribute('value').then(console.log);
    });

});
```

Notice that calling `.getText()` will return nothing. To get text from inputs and textarea use `.getAttribute('value')`

Comment: This will add text at the end, but i need to add text in between the lines of text.